# React access state of nested child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management

I need to access (read and manipulate) the state of a different component. Unfortunately the case isn't just a "simple" Parent <-> Child relation, but a bit more complicated.

**SendResults** has a button on which if I click I want to read a state property of the **Vote** component.

I don't really know how to solve this the problem.

Here's the Component Graph:

```js
Table
  TableHeader
  TableBody
    ResultRow
      Result
      Result
    ParticipantRow
      Vote
      Vote
  TableFooter
    SendResults
```

Comment: You need to use Redux for this kind of problem. By using Redux you can pass from a component to any component even without making a parent-child relationship between them. There are many good tutorials out there

Comment: @BurakGavas is right. You need to use a third-party library like Redux, Flux, React-Saga, etc.

Comment: I have never worked with Redux. Is this a common thing to do without any "deeper" learning/understanding of it?

Comment: It will take some time to learn it. But if you are using Reactjs, then you need to know at least 1 of those libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Context API`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) (for a simple use-case like this).

The question that always comes after ["Should I use a state management library like Redux or MobX instead"](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#should-i-use-a-state-management-library-like-redux-or-mobx).